# Breaking a forloop

Tags: python, django

I am currently working on my first website. A dna to protein translator. Here's the thing, when you input the codon (group of three letters) tga,tag or taa. The forloop should stop.
Basically, I want to stop the forloop
Here's the code:

```
class TranslatorView(View):
    template_name = 'main/translated.html'

    
    def translate_amino(self, codon):
        return self.amino_mapper.get(codon, "")


   

    def build_protein(self, phrase): #Here's the main problem
        protein = []
        i = 0
        while i < len(phrase):
            codon = phrase[i: i + 3]
            amino = self.translate_amino(codon)
            if amino:
                protein.append(amino)
            elif amino == "tag","tga","taa":
                break amino
                
            else:
                print(f"The codon {codon} is not in self.amino_mapper")
            i += 3
        return protein
```

However, I'm experiencing some errors. Does anyone know how to solve them.

By the way, the main problem is in the def build_protein, it raises a syntax error in the condition where I try to break the code

Comment: Could you please explain why you tagged this with with HTML and CSS? They do not appear relevant at all, unless I'm missing something

Comment: What errors? Could you post them as well?

Comment: It's a syntax error in the condition where I try to break the code. I've edited it know so you  can see it

Comment: Sorry, I've already erased them

Comment: What do you expect `amino == "tag","tga","taa"` to mean?

Comment: Include your error messages. `break amino` is not valid Python. What are you hoping to do here? Return amino as the result of the function?

Comment: In the dictionary amino_mapper,  the groups of letters tag, tga and taa mean that the dna chain stops. So I want to break the forloop

Comment: I'm hoping to stop the forloop

Comment: You really should make sure your fundamentals are more solid before attempting a project like this. You are running before you can walk.

Comment: I know, at first this was a learning project. But as I was coding, I began to make important changes and my fundamentals aren't perfect

Comment: While I'm coding I'm also looking for documentation to learn

Comment: Stopping a loop is contained in any tutorial on loops.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.  Posting 170 lines of code is excessive; asking us to teach you a fundamental language feature is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
if amino:
    protein.append(amino)
elif amino == "tag","tga","taa":
```

If/else statements gets executed from top to bottom, in your case the `elif` never gets executed because even if `amino == 'tag'` the `if` statement gets executed.
Also `break amino` is not a valid syntax and you should write the elif like this:

```
elif amino in ("tag","tga","taa"):
```

Answer (score 0):

the break statement doesn't return any value you can set
a variable right before you break out of the loop and then check what the value is in side the loop

```
def build_protein(self, phrase): #Here's the main problem
    protein = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(phrase):
        codon = phrase[i: i + 3]
        amino = self.translate_amino(codon)
        if amino:
            protein.append(amino)
        elif amino == "tag","tga","taa":
            new_amino=amino
            break
            
        else:
            print(f"The codon {codon} is not in self.amino_mapper")
        i += 3
    if new_amino:
       # do whatever
    return protein
```